# Using certificate file to connect to webservice over SSL

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, windows-services, ssl-certificate

I am developing windows service in C# which invokes webservice methods. I must use SSL to connect to webservice. I have recieved from publisher p12 file with certificate. The file is password protected. To use Import method to use this certificate. Everything is working fine, but I do not like this method - I have password harcoded in my app. When publisher changes certificate I must rewrite code(changing the password to new one). Is there any way not to harcode password to .p12 file or use other option(.cer file)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PKCS#12 file is provided to you as it is a natural way to transport certificates together with private keys. You can use one of the following:

- convert it to format you like and store the way you like
- convert it to passwordless PFX
- import it to computer's certificate storage and use it this way

But all those methods (together with keeping a hardcoded password) provide no real protection to the private key and thus are not usable if you distribute the application to outside of your organization.

Answer (score 5):

What you could do is something like this:

1. Install the SSL certificate into your local machine certificate store (using the Microsoft Management Console "MMC")
2. Extract the certificates thumbprint (e.g. "748681ca3646ccc7c4facb7360a0e3baa0894cb5")
3. Use a function which fetches you the certificate from the local certificate store for the given thumbprint.
4. Provide the SSL certificate when calling your web service.

```
private static X509Certificate2 GetCertificateByThumbprint(string certificateThumbPrint, StoreLocation certificateStoreLocation) {
    X509Certificate2 certificate = null;

    X509Store certificateStore = new X509Store(certificateStoreLocation);
    certificateStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);


    X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = certificateStore.Certificates;
    foreach (X509Certificate2 cert in certCollection)
    {
        if (cert.Thumbprint != null && cert.Thumbprint.Equals(certificateThumbPrint, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            certificate = cert;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (certificate == null)
    {
        Log.ErrorFormat(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Certificate with thumbprint {0} not found", certificateThumbPrint);
    }

    return certificate;
}

public string GetServiceResponse() {
    string WebSvcEndpointConfigurationName = "WebServiceEndpoint";
    Uri webSvcEndpointAddress = new Uri("http://www.example.com/YourWebService.svc");
    string webSvcCertificateThumbPrint = "748681ca3646ccc7c4facb7360a0e3baa0894cb5";

    string webSvcResponse = null;
    SomeWebServiceClient webServiceClient = null;

    try
    {
        webServiceClient = new SomeWebServiceClient(WebSvcEndpointConfigurationName, new EndpointAddress(webSvcEndpointAddress));
        webServiceClient.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = GetCertificateByThumbprint(webSvcCertificateThumbPrint, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);

        webSvcResponse = webServiceClient.GetServiceResponse();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        if (webServiceClient != null)
        {
            webServiceClient.Close();
        }
    }
    return webSvcResponse;
}
```

Comment: HI There, may i know what should i put for the SomeWebServiceClient class? I have added a service referenece class called "PlanningService" (a wsdl service reference) and it does not have any property callled ClientCredentials. Does the class need to be a type of a particular kind of object? Thanks.